# Begining Java student

Tags: java, eclipse, string, switch-statement

I am writing a program where i have to use methods to count my string, .upper and lower using a switch statement. My code is not showing any errors can someone help.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Strings
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String selection;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("*********** EXAM 3 ENTER A STRING *************");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to display the number of words in the string");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 to display the string in all capital letters");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 to display the string in all lower case letters");  
        System.out.println("Enter 4 to display the string in reverse order");
        System.out.println("Enter -1 to exit");
        selection = keyboard.nextLine();

        switch(selection.charAt(0))
        {
        case 1:
            numberOfWords(selection);
            break;
        case 2:
            allCapitals(selection);
            break;
        case 3:
            allLowers(selection);
            break;
        case 4:
            reverseOrder(selection);
            break;



        }//ends switch


    }

    /*public static void menuMethod(String [] args)
    {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.println("*********** EXAM 3 ENTER A STRING *************");
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to display the number of words in the string");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 to display the string in all capital letters");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 to display the string in all lower case letters");  
        System.out.println("Enter 4 to display the string in reverse order");
        System.out.println("Enter -1 to exit");



        }
       */







       public static void numberOfWords(String selection)
        {

          String input;  // To hold input


          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


          System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
          input = keyboard.nextLine();

          // Display the number of words.
          System.out.println("That string has " + wordCount(input) + " words in it.");



       }
       public static int wordCount(String str)
       {
          StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(str);
          return strTok.countTokens();
       }


       public static void allCapitals (String str)
       {
        String input;
        String capInput;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a string. ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();//You must use nextLine here next will not work.

        capInput = input.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("Your capital case string = \n" + capInput); 
       }

       public static void allLowers (String str)
       {
        String input;
        String lowerInput;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a string. ");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();//You must use nextLine here next will not work.

        lowerInput = input.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("Your lower case string = \n" + lowerInput); 
       }

       public static void reverseOrder (String str)
       {
          String input;  // To hold input


          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


          System.out.print("Enter something: ");
          input = keyboard.nextLine();

          // Display it backwards.
          backward(input);
       }


       public static void backward(String str)
       {
          for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
             System.out.print(str.charAt(i));
          System.out.println();
       }


}
```

Comment: If your code is not having any errors, what's the problem then? Are you not getting expected output? Then put the input, the output you are getting and what you expect. Also edit the question to better reflect the problem.

Comment: You question title needs to be updated to provide some idea of what the problem you're having is, also, it helps if you ask an actual question

Comment: "Begining Java student" is not a question.  What do you need help with?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this code for switch

```
 switch(selection.charAt(0))

        {

        case '1':
            numberOfWords(selection);
            break;

        case '2':
            allCapitals(selection);
            break;

        case '3':
            allLowers(selection);
            break;

        case '4':
            reverseOrder(selection);
            break;

        }//ends switch
```

Comment: Care to explain what this does, why the original version was bad, and why this is better?  Code with no context is not helpful.

Comment: you are giving a charecter in switch not a number. So you have to specify a character in switch not 1 instead use '1' . As it is a character not a number

Answer (score 2):

replace your switch condition to

```
switch(Integer.parseInt(selection))
{
//your code
}
```

instead of

```
switch(selection.charAt(0))
{
  //your code
}
```

if you use `charAt(0)` your checking condition must be like that because that method returns a char value

```
    case '1':
        numberOfWords(selection);
        break;
    case '2':
        allCapitals(selection);
        break;
    case '3':
        allLowers(selection);
        break;
    case '4':
        reverseOrder(selection);
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what is wrong with the program output. Explaining your problem as thoroughly as possible will help you get a good answer quickly.

As for possible problems:

1. Your `allLowers()` method is using `toUpperCase()`. As a good design practice, try to copy paste code as little as possible, since copy/pasting code implies that there could be a function that does the same thing.
2. You are never actually checking for an input of `-1`. All you would do in your current method (if you were to check for the exit condition) is check for the `-` sign as that is the first character, rather that the entire `-1` string, which could easily lead to bugs if you expand the program.

Comment: He actually doesn't need to check for -1. If the user enters -1 then the program will just exit because there isn't a check for that in the switch statement.

Comment: I understand that there is no need to check for -1, but by not checking, it introduces potentially unwanted behavior since the user could enter } and be able to exit. It's just a design preference, but deliberately checking helps code be self documenting and generally have fewer bugs.